# Longest distance to goal for top 5 European league?

Tags: football, trivia, la-liga, serie-a, bundesliga

Stoke City goalkeeper [Asmir Begovic's 91.9 metres (301ft 6in)](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sport/football/article-2743245/Asmir-Begovic-world-beater-Stoke-keeper-s-goal-92-metres-officially-named-longest-goal-scored-football.html) goal against Southampton is the longest goal scored in the Premier League.

So, what is the longest goal scored in other top European leagues?

Comment: @gdrt Not sure about those three added tag though.

Comment: Why? Isn't the question explicitly asking for the records achieved in La Liga, Bundesliga, Serie A and Ligue 1?

Comment: @gdrt That is right but back when I suggested edit for similar type of question, my edit got rejected. Stating: This edit introduces tags that do not help to define the topic of the question. Tags should help to describe what the question is about, not just what it contains. I don't mind though just letting you know.

Comment: IMO, your question is about records of top 5 leagues. And if there are different subjective opinions about that, I would encourage you to start a meta topic about tagging the series of questions you've already asked about top 5 leagues. I would contribute to that meta with my 5 cents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**German Bundesliga**: [Moritz Stoppelkamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moritz_Stoppelkamp) for *SC Paderborn* against Hannover 96 in *2014/15 season* from **83 meters**. **[Video](https://youtu.be/6dJXByywQbI?t=3s)**, source: [**bundesliga.com** - German](http://www.bundesliga.com/de/bundesliga/news/rekordtor-moritz-stoppelkamp-sc-paderborn.jsp).

**Italian Serie A**: [Enzo Ferrari](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enzo_Ferrari_(footballer)) for *Palermo* against Roma in 1968/69 season from **77 meters**. Source: [**forzapalermo.it** - Italian](https://www.forzapalermo.it/news/enzo-ferrari-no-ferrari-enzo.html), [**gazetta.it** - Italian](http://www.gazzetta.it/Calcio/Primo_Piano/2008/01_Gennaio/26/ferrari.shtml).

**Spanish La Liga**: [Antonio José González Santos](http://www.bdfutbol.com/en/j/j261.html) for *Numancia* against Sevilla in *2004/05 season* from **68 meters**. **[Videoǂ](https://youtu.be/Ocywf8rTdiI?t=9s)**, source: [**elmundo** - Spanish](http://www.elmundo.es/deportes/2014/09/21/541ef5de22601d44538b457b.html), [**marca** - Spanish](http://www.marca.com/2011/10/02/futbol/1adivision/1317575790.html).

---

ǂ *Video has a very poor quality, and player's team information label is wrong, i.e Levante instead of Numancia, probably because they have similar outfits.

Comment: Couldn't find an information for French Ligue 1.

Comment: Accepting your answer for now and will let you know if I find about Ligue 1.